# Adding Android Image Cropper library throws an error

Tags: java, android, sdk

When I add this library to my Android app project it gives me an error:

"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

(and 3 more errors like that)

It also takes me to v23/values-v23.xml file where this line is marked:

My minSdkVersion is 15, targetSdkVersion 21 and compileSdkVersion 21. And these should stay as they are, I guess?

I am using Android Image Cropper 2.1.4 so i assume it means that it should run fine on compileSdkVersion 21.

Could anyone give me some hints how to solve this problem?

I am a bit new to Android development

Comment: link to the library https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/Change-Log?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3487

Comment: You need to update your `compileSdkVersion` to 23 because the project you are trying to add , targets 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that these errors arise after including this library to you project, than surely this library is making use of some *style resource* that inherits from the parent resource *TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse* that does not exist. This issue will be resolved by inheriting from a parent resource that exists (setting targetSDKVersion to at-least what library uses).

Secondly it will be better to change your targetSDKVersion to the newest one and compileSDKVersion to the latest one. That is what one usually does when writing an application. Everyone wants to target all the new devices to be able to use one's application.

So try changing target and compile SDKVerisons.
Change SDKVersions to the latest one.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to change the configuration so that it would inherit from parent resource that actually exists?  And another question, if I will change targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to a newer ones how then it will effect my app's users? Will those who have lower Android API system then the one i will set as my targer/compile will be able to run the app still?

Comment: Your minimumSDK version accounts for supporting lower end devices and as you say you have set it to 15, so it will keep on supporting devices with version as low as 15. While targetSDK version if set to latest will enable your app to be used by higher end devices also. Changing this to latest should resolve your issue.

Comment: This library is using targetSDKVersion 24 and that is the cause of this problem.

Comment: Is there a way somehow to change libraries target version?