# Crop picture on Android phone

Tags: java, android, crop

Have a question.

Can anyone give me some example of how to write an image cropping functionality for Android (taking pictures from library of camera)? I have found plenty of examples with staff like:
**Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");**
However, this kind of approach does not work on all the phones.
Libraries are also not suitable in my case.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: "Libraries are also not suitable in my case" -- why not? Everything in Android is based on libraries. If nothing else, many [image cropping libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) are open source, and so you can use them to learn how to write your own.

Comment: Because as much as i understand most of those third party libraries are are targeting 23 sdk and the project i need to build cropping functionality is targeting api 21. Changing it to api 23 just messes things apart (:

Comment: @Kasparas You need to understand the difference between targetSDK and minSDK.  target is what tool version it was written with.  Min is the minimum is can use.  It is not only acceptable but very normal to have a target SDK at 23 or so and a minimum in the low to mid teens.  Realistically you shouldn't even have to look at the target of a library, just the minimum.  Also I can't think of any functionality added in later SDKs that a cropping library would rely on.

Comment: @Kasparas you are lucky to get the first comment from CommonsWare

Comment: Neither the `compileSdkVersion` nor the `targetSdkVersion` of the libraries should affect your app. The `minSdkVersion` would, and [most of those libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) have a `minSdkVersion` well below 21. If you are having problems using one of those libraries, ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and explaining in detail what your issues are.

Comment: Well, i have one small project with third party cropping library implemented which works fine when both target and compile are 23. Minimum is 15. However, when i change target and compile into 21 then i get such error: "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name ....". So i guess target and compile level could have some effect? I am pretty new to Android development...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why you don't want to use libraries in your app. Why would you want to **spend so much time re-writing and tackling all the edge cases** something that someone has already done?

Here are some amazing cropping libraries. I have used these in production with 100K+ users and never had a crash or any issue with them.

1) [uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop)

2) [android-crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)

3) [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

If you are still not convinced and want to make your own, then you should start looking at the codes of these projects. **They are open-source**.

And moreover, it is not possible to explain all the details of making an image cropper in a single SO answer.

Comment: Hey, I explained my not willingness of using libraries in my last comment (:

Comment: None of the libraries mentioned have a minimum SDK version of 21. You can easily use them. Hope it solves your issue. If so, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I actually used the nr.3 You provided in the list and it gave me the error i wrote down in my last comment. And i honestly have no clue how should i solve it. I already asked a question about it, but didn't get any decent answers.

Comment: I recommend you to try the first or the second one more. I am currently using both of them in two of my projects.

Comment: I tried uCrop yesterday actually, and it gave me the same problem. If i set target and compile both to be api 21, then iget the exact error.

Comment: Then you are surely using them in a wrong way. All these libraries can't be faulty at the same time. Try the second one.

Comment: but what is then the right way? If it woudn't work entirelly then i would agree, but mine only breaks when i set those things to 21.

Comment: That is an entirely different question. If this question is solved, mark it as accepted and ask another question with full details and give me the link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160657/adding-android-image-cropper-library-throws-an-error?noredirect=1#comment71486613_42160657